# Difference between geothermal and regular hydronic zone valves

Tags: valve, hydronic, zoned-heating

Taco makes two variants of zone valves - one type for general hydronic use, and another type marketed especially for geothermal use.

**What is the difference in valves that particularly suits them for one application or the other?**

All the manufacturer's literature I can find (so far) basically reads identically for [both](http://www.tacocomfort.com/products/hydronic_accessories/zone_and_flow_control_valves/zone_sentry_zone_valve/index.html) [products](http://www.tacocomfort.com/products/hydronic_accessories/zone_and_flow_control_valves/zone_sentry_zone_valve/geo-sentry_geothermal_zone_valve/index.html). But the geothermal variants are more expensive. Having looked at samples myself, I don't see any superficially obvious differences. The actual valve portions appear to be potentially identical; but there could be some differences in the actuators ether mechanically or electronically which would not be obvious.

(Perhaps other manufacturers have a similar offering, I just happen to be a little familiar with Taco's).

---

Assuming there are substantive differences, in a pinch could one be used in the "wrong" application successfully? (e.g., using a regular hydronic in a geothermal system, or vice-versa).

---

Note - both samples I've seen are normally closed, so apparently the answer is not that one is normally open.

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There may be other differences as well but the geothermal valve is designed for a higher head pressure.  The standard hydronic system is built around reduced pressure. The geothermal valve is expected to deal with standard water pumping and or city pressure.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Is the difference in pressure capability going to be like a PSI rating in the literature? And is this a difference in the valve body or in the actuator (or both)?

Comment: Regarding pressure either body can handle all kinds of pressure.  The actuator of the geo valve is going to be loaded all together different.

Answer (score 1):

*This comment pertains specifically to Taco valves, it may or may not be true of other valves intended for geothermal applications. Not all geo systems are open loop.*

---

> [The geothermal valve] is made from materials that can resist oxygen
>   corrosion more effectively than those in a Zone Sentry valve. Zone
>   Sentry valves are designed for use in closed-loop systems, but
>   Geo-Sentry valves are designed for use in open-loop geothermal
>   systems. Open-loop systems contain fresh oxygen.

(From Q&A section at [this page](https://www.supplyhouse.com/Taco-V075T2G2ZA024Q4A1-3-4-Geo-Sentry-GeoThermal-Zone-Valve-Normally-Closed-Threaded).)

---

This was also confirmed by information I received directly from a manufacturer in reply to asking this same question:

> A standard hydronic valve is made of free machining brass. When exposed to oxygen, it will
>   dezincify. (The oxygen pulls the zinc out of the brass making it
>   brittle and porous.) A geothermal specific valve uses brass that can handle open
>   systems (O2) and will not dezincify. The bottom line is that the normal hydronic valves are not made for open systems.